# Merge several sheet from googlesheet into on PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Spreadsheet with around 40 sheets. I want to export them to PDF using a googlescript (to export only the desired range on each of the sheets). I manage to do it (using HtmlService.createHtmlOutput...), but I get the infamous 429 error. Of course, I can introduce pauses to export all the sheets, but I need it to be fast.

My idea is to combine the different sheets into a single PDF and then download it all at once. Is it possible using a blob? What suggestion do you advise?

My code :

```
 function impressionPDF() {
  var ClasseurID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
  var jourPeriodique = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("JOURNAL_PERIODIQUE")
  var formulaire = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FORMULAIRE")
  var annee =jourPeriodique.getRange("d2").getValue(); // cell with a date
  var anneeuniquement = new Date(annee).getFullYear(); // Year for file naming

 listeImpression = formulaire.getRange("L1:AL1").getValues()[0]; // Array of the sheet I like to print



for (var i = 0; i < listeImpression.length; i++) {
  NomFeuille = listeImpression[i];
  Onglet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(NomFeuille)
  OngletID = Onglet.getSheetId()

  // those 3 lines are for finding the last row into column A
  Depart = Onglet.getRange("A5");
  DernierRang = Depart.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  Plage = "A1:J" + DernierRang

  /// Generating the Html 
urlPDF = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' +
      ClasseurID +
      '/export?format=pdf&printnotes=false&size=A4&portrait=true&fitw=true&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.7&right_margin=0.7&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&gridlines=true&fzr=FALSE&gid=' +
      OngletID +
      '&range=' +
      Plage;

  Logger.log(urlPDF)
  var NomfichierPDF = "PPE_Nord11-13_" + anneeuniquement + "_" + NomFeuille;//custom pdf name here 

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlPDF, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<a target ="_blank" download="' +
        NomfichierPDF +
        '" href = "data:application/pdf;base64,' +
        Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()) +
        '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
        '<script> \
        var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
        a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,10)}); \
        a.click(); \
        </script>'
    ).setHeight(50),
    'Downloading PDF..'
  );
  // wait before the loop
  Utilities.sleep(1000)

}

}
```

Comment: Please share all the codes (not as image so we can easily copy your code) OR you can also share a sample spreadsheet with the script you are using. If you can add a screenshot of the `402 error` that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! you will fin the code into my edited post.

Comment: sorry, the error is 429 not 402

Comment: The idea of combining the different sheets into a single PDF is possible by creating a master sheet however the ranges will be compiled instead of showing per pages. Are you fine with this suggestion?

Comment: Hello, it could be a solution, but not the best for what I need. I would like to print (in PDF) each GoogleSheet sheet on one page only.